# Alpha transparency is not working for my Shader when used to see objects behind the foreground layer

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I wish to have alpha transparency on my shader that enables characters to be seen behind foreground layers (without completely removing them). However, it is either fully on or fully off! I've been tweaking with a shader without much luck! Here is the shader:

```
Shader "Universal Render Pipeline/2D/EntityForegroundTrancparency"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex("Base (RGB) Trans (A)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _MaskTex("Mask", 2D) = "white" {}
        _NormalMap("Normal Map", 2D) = "bump" {}
        _Transparency("Transparency", Range(0.0,0.5)) = 0.25

        // Legacy properties. They're here so that materials using this shader can gracefully fallback to the legacy sprite shader.
        [HideInInspector] _Color("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        [HideInInspector] _RendererColor("RendererColor", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        [HideInInspector] _Flip("Flip", Vector) = (1,1,1,1)
        [HideInInspector] _AlphaTex("External Alpha", 2D) = "white" {}
        [HideInInspector] _EnableExternalAlpha("Enable External Alpha", Float) = 0
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags {"Queue" = "Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType" = "Transparent" }

        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha, One OneMinusSrcAlpha
        Cull Off
        ZWrite Off

        Stencil
        {
            Ref 1
            Comp Always
            Pass Replace
        }

        Pass
        {
            Tags { "LightMode" = "Universal2D" }

            HLSLPROGRAM
            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/ShaderLibrary/Core.hlsl"

            #pragma vertex CombinedShapeLightVertex
            #pragma fragment CombinedShapeLightFragment

            #pragma multi_compile USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_0 __
            #pragma multi_compile USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_1 __
            #pragma multi_compile USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_2 __
            #pragma multi_compile USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_3 __
            #pragma multi_compile _ DEBUG_DISPLAY

            struct Attributes
            {
                float3 positionOS   : POSITION;
                float4 color        : COLOR;
                float2  uv          : TEXCOORD0;
                UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
            };

            struct Varyings
            {
                float4  positionCS  : SV_POSITION;
                half4   color       : COLOR;
                float2  uv          : TEXCOORD0;
                half2   lightingUV  : TEXCOORD1;
                #if defined(DEBUG_DISPLAY)
                float3  positionWS  : TEXCOORD2;
                #endif
                UNITY_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO
            };

            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/2D/Include/LightingUtility.hlsl"

            TEXTURE2D(_MainTex);
            SAMPLER(sampler_MainTex);
            TEXTURE2D(_MaskTex);
            SAMPLER(sampler_MaskTex);
            half4 _MainTex_ST;
            float _Transparency;

            #if USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_0
            SHAPE_LIGHT(0)
            #endif

            #if USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_1
            SHAPE_LIGHT(1)
            #endif

            #if USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_2
            SHAPE_LIGHT(2)
            #endif

            #if USE_SHAPE_LIGHT_TYPE_3
            SHAPE_LIGHT(3)
            #endif

            Varyings CombinedShapeLightVertex(Attributes v)
            {
                Varyings o = (Varyings)0;
                UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(v);
                UNITY_INITIALIZE_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO(o);

                o.positionCS = TransformObjectToHClip(v.positionOS);
                #if defined(DEBUG_DISPLAY)
                o.positionWS = TransformObjectToWorld(v.positionOS);
                #endif
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                o.lightingUV = half2(ComputeScreenPos(o.positionCS / o.positionCS.w).xy);

                o.color = v.color;
                o.color.a = _Transparency;
                return o;
            }

            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/2D/Include/CombinedShapeLightShared.hlsl"

            half4 CombinedShapeLightFragment(Varyings i) : SV_Target
            {
                i.color.a = _Transparency;
                half4 main = i.color * SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_MainTex, sampler_MainTex, i.uv);
                half4 mask = i.color * SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_MaskTex, sampler_MaskTex, i.uv);
                SurfaceData2D surfaceData;
                InputData2D inputData;

                InitializeSurfaceData(main.rgb, _Transparency, mask, surfaceData);
                InitializeInputData(i.uv, i.lightingUV, inputData);

                return CombinedShapeLightShared(surfaceData, inputData);
            }
            ENDHLSL
        }

        Pass
        {
            Tags { "LightMode" = "NormalsRendering"}

            HLSLPROGRAM
            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/ShaderLibrary/Core.hlsl"

            #pragma vertex NormalsRenderingVertex
            #pragma fragment NormalsRenderingFragment

            struct Attributes
            {
                float3 positionOS   : POSITION;
                float4 color        : COLOR;
                float2 uv           : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 tangent      : TANGENT;
                UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
            };

            struct Varyings
            {
                float4  positionCS      : SV_POSITION;
                half4   color           : COLOR;
                float2  uv              : TEXCOORD0;
                half3   normalWS        : TEXCOORD1;
                half3   tangentWS       : TEXCOORD2;
                half3   bitangentWS     : TEXCOORD3;
                UNITY_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO
            };

            TEXTURE2D(_MainTex);
            SAMPLER(sampler_MainTex);
            TEXTURE2D(_NormalMap);
            SAMPLER(sampler_NormalMap);
            half4 _NormalMap_ST;  // Is this the right way to do this?
            float _Transparency;

            Varyings NormalsRenderingVertex(Attributes attributes)
            {
                Varyings o = (Varyings)0;
                UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(attributes);
                UNITY_INITIALIZE_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO(o);

                o.positionCS = TransformObjectToHClip(attributes.positionOS);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(attributes.uv, _NormalMap);
                o.color = attributes.color;
                o.color.a = _Transparency;
                o.normalWS = -GetViewForwardDir();
                o.tangentWS = TransformObjectToWorldDir(attributes.tangent.xyz);
                o.bitangentWS = cross(o.normalWS, o.tangentWS) * attributes.tangent.w;
                return o;
            }

            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/2D/Include/NormalsRenderingShared.hlsl"

            half4 NormalsRenderingFragment(Varyings i) : SV_Target
            {
                i.color.a = _Transparency;
                const half4 mainTex = i.color * SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_MainTex, sampler_MainTex, i.uv);
                const half3 normalTS = UnpackNormal(SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_NormalMap, sampler_NormalMap, i.uv));

                return NormalsRenderingShared(mainTex, normalTS, i.tangentWS.xyz, i.bitangentWS.xyz, i.normalWS.xyz);
            }
            ENDHLSL
        }

        Pass
        {
            Tags { "LightMode" = "UniversalForward" "Queue"="Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent"}

            HLSLPROGRAM
            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/ShaderLibrary/Core.hlsl"

            #pragma vertex UnlitVertex
            #pragma fragment UnlitFragment

            struct Attributes
            {
                float3 positionOS   : POSITION;
                float4 color        : COLOR;
                float2 uv           : TEXCOORD0;
                UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
            };

            struct Varyings
            {
                float4  positionCS      : SV_POSITION;
                float4  color           : COLOR;
                float2  uv              : TEXCOORD0;
                #if defined(DEBUG_DISPLAY)
                float3  positionWS  : TEXCOORD2;
                #endif
                UNITY_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO
            };

            TEXTURE2D(_MainTex);
            SAMPLER(sampler_MainTex);
            float4 _MainTex_ST;
            float _Transparency;

            Varyings UnlitVertex(Attributes attributes)
            {
                Varyings o = (Varyings)0;
                UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(attributes);
                UNITY_INITIALIZE_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO(o);

                o.positionCS = TransformObjectToHClip(attributes.positionOS);
                #if defined(DEBUG_DISPLAY)
                o.positionWS = TransformObjectToWorld(v.positionOS);
                #endif
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(attributes.uv, _MainTex);
                o.color = attributes.color;
                o.color.a = _Transparency;
                return o;
            }

            float4 UnlitFragment(Varyings i) : SV_Target
            {
                i.color.a = _Transparency;
                float4 mainTex = i.color * SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_MainTex, sampler_MainTex, i.uv);

                #if defined(DEBUG_DISPLAY)
                SurfaceData2D surfaceData;
                InputData2D inputData;
                half4 debugColor = 0;

                InitializeSurfaceData(mainTex.rgb, _Transparency, surfaceData);
                InitializeInputData(i.uv, inputData);
                SETUP_DEBUG_DATA_2D(inputData, i.positionWS);

                if(CanDebugOverrideOutputColor(surfaceData, inputData, debugColor))
                {
                    return debugColor;
                }
                #endif

                return mainTex;
            }
            ENDHLSL
        }
    }

    Fallback "Sprites/Default"
}
```

As you can see from the following video, alpha seems to be completely ignored:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUTKF-bIdD8

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a pretty complicated shader -- you've got transparency, lighting, stencils ... Please read and follow the guidelines on [how to create a MINIMAL reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

If this is from an existing shade, which shader did you start from? What are the changes that you made?